# Logging every time a database table is updated

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, nopcommerce

Ok so in nopcommerce we have the customers table.

```
private readonly IRepository<Customer> _customerRepository;
```

is there some kind of way to listen or hook into an event, so every time that database table is updated I can set a break point which gets triggered.

It would really help me to find where the problem I'm having is, where excessive guest accounts are being created.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about nopcommerce but normally you can use triggers https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38808/Overview-of-SQL-Server-database-Triggers

Comment: NopCommerce has an eventPublisher and you can write your own eventListener for each entity you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific hook for a guest customer, however you can achieve by two methods.
First, using an event, nopCommerce providing types of events to preform post logic.
So, whenever record inserted or updated, you will get a call on your custom event.

```
IConsumer<EntityInserted<Customer>>
```

Second way is, implement action filter for customer method.

Good read: [Exposing and Handling Events](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/en/Exposing+and+Handling+Events)

Comment: Glad I could help you :)